# Flot chart showing negative values but it doesn't have any

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm using this data:

```
{
    label: 'Payments',
    // data: this.getFlotPaymentData(),
    data: [
      [Moment().subtract(6, 'days').valueOf(), 0],
      [Moment().subtract(5, 'days').valueOf(), 0],
      [Moment().subtract(4, 'days').valueOf(), 0],
      [Moment().subtract(3, 'days').valueOf(), 0],
      [Moment().subtract(2, 'days').valueOf(), 168.50],
      [Moment().subtract(1, 'days').valueOf(), 200.00],
      [Moment().valueOf(), 200.00]
    ],
    last: false
}
```

and for some reason, my graph goes into negative values. I'm expecting it to be zero until 2 days ago then suddenly jump to 168.50.

I don't want to set the min value of the graph to 0 because I have another data set being introduced which goes into negative values (expenses).

It's producing this:

[image]

I'm initialising flot like so:

```
// Chart options
var chart = $('#flot-visitors')
var labelColor = chart.css('color')
var options = {
  colors: chart.data('color').split(','),
  series: {
    shadowSize: 0,
    lines: {
      show: true,
      lineWidth: false,
      fill: true
    },
    curvedLines: {
      apply: true,
      active: true,
      monotonicFit: false
    }
  },
  legend: {
    container: $('#flot-visitors-legend')
  },
  xaxis: {
    mode: 'time',
    timeformat: '%d %b',
    font: {color: labelColor}
  },
  yaxis: {
    font: {color: labelColor}
  },
  grid: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    color: labelColor,
    hoverable: true
  }
}
chart.width('100%')

// Create chart
$.plot(chart, data, options)
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with the bezier curve algorithm being used, rather than a data problem. I'm not familiar with Flot, but check to see if you can amend the line smoothing algorithm - I'd guess the `curvedLines` property.

Comment: maybe set `monotonicFit: true`.

Comment: Yep, Rory's right. I've seen this problem before. Here's a link to a list of people having the same (unrelated library): https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/424

Comment: @NinaScholz - That does indeed solve the negative issue! Thanks. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept. The curve is still in place though from the 5th curving up to the 168 value, would you expect that (as a user / developer)? Edit: Setting `curvedLines: false` sorts the odd looking curve data out.

Comment: p.s Thanks for the feedback guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Documentation](https://github.com/MichaelZinsmaier/CurvedLines), you could set

```
monotonicFit: true
```

> ```
> parameter    type effect
> ------------ ---- -----------------------------------------------------------------
> monotonicFit bool true => uses monotone cubic interpolation (preserve monotonicity)
> ```